# Customize UP arrow ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, customization, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionBarSherlock. In one of my Activities I have SearchView. When it expands i change background of ABS from gree to white. So I need to change Up arrow too. Well, the question is: how can i change its color or set ImageResource on it from code?